# getting an exception on running sample of wso2cep

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

I am a beginner in wso2cep. I want to execute the first sample of WSO2 CEP documentation. I use windows10 as operating system. I type the following command but i getting following exeption in Console output:

```
c:\wso2cep-4.0.0\samples\producers\http>ant Durl=http://localhost:9763/endpoints/httpReceiver -Dsn=0001
Buildfile: c:\wso2cep-4.0.0\samples\producers\http\build.xml 
init:
compile:
[javac] c:\wso2cep-4.0.0\samples\producers\http\build.xml:71: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to 
false
for repeatable builds
 [copy] Copying 1 file to c:\wso2cep-4.0.0\samples\producers\http\temp\classes

run:
[echo]  Configure -Durl=xxxx and ( -DfilePath=xxxx or -Dsn='sample number')
optionally use -Dusername=xxxx -Dpassword=xxxx
[java] [main] INFO  org.wso2.carbon.sample.http.Http  - Starting WSO2 Http
Client
[java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:4
[java]     at org.wso2.carbon.sample.http.Http.main(Unknown Source)
[java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
```

I add this line: `<property name="filePath" value="&quot;&quot;"/>` to the build.xml file but I still get above exception. My build.xml file become as following:

```
<property name="carbon.home" value="${basedir}"/>

<property name="lib" value="${carbon.home}/repository/lib"/>
<property name="tempdir" value="${carbon.home}/tmp/setup"/>
<property name="output.dir" value="${carbon.home}/tmp/wso2"/>
<property name="filePath" value="&quot;&quot;"/>
```

Should i change "filePath" to another thing? Should i add this line to build.xml file or change other lines? Please help and explain to me.

Comment: This is a known bug when running on windows https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-1474 could you please recheck if you correctly change the build.xml file as mentioned in the JIRA

Comment: My problem has been solved. Thank you very much.